# Reset mutable class fields

Tags: java, class, java-8

Say I have a class with some mutable fields:

```
public class Test
{
    private boolean isCorrect;
    private String userId;

    public void run() {...}
    
    // more methods
}
```

The `run()` method will be modifying these fields. My issues is that the caller of this class might call `run()` any number of times, and for this reason I should be re-setting the fields back to `null`.

My question is, what is the best practice for this scenario? Should I reset the fields every time the method is called?

```
public void run()
{
    isCorrect = null;
    userId = null;
    // do stuff
}
```

Or is there a cleaner/smarter approach to this?

Comment: Is there any reason not to use local variables instead of fields?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I'm assuming other methods in the class are relying on these values as well

Comment: Is it desired for you that the caller might call `run()` several times, or is this just for making sure nothing stupid happens?

Comment: @paladin it shouldn't be called multiple times, but as you say, in case something stupid happens.

Comment: I would try to avoid concurrent access to the field if possible because it's harder implement it correctly and just not necessary for many cases. Instead, I would try to create new instance for each run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is use local variables. The OP has clarified in the comments that `run` calls other methods on the same instance that expect to use these variable too.

The class should be split. The `run` method should create an object containing the fields and call methods on that.

```
public class Test {

    public void run() {
         TestImpl impl = new TestImpl();
         impl.run();
    }
    
    // more methods
}
class TestImpl {
    private boolean isCorrect;
    private String userId;

    public void run() {...}
    
    // more methods
}
```

You could make the new class a nested class, though that does cause excessive indention. An inner class would also have direct access to any longer lived variables of `Test`. An anonymous inner class (or, more obscurely, a local class) would be even more convenient but indented.

Comment: Using this method is valid, but it has the ability to make it easier to create undefined program states. You better use exceptions like in my example. Allowing the user to use a program in an invalid way creates a lot of overhead, it's better to disallow such behaviour in the first place.

Comment: Not sure to understand how that prevents the OP need to reset the fields before each call.

Comment: @paladin The OP states no requirement that the method must not be executed concurrently. That's an entirely separate issue and best dealt with using `synchronized` (or `Semaphore` to also prevent recursive access, as Java lock are unfortunately re-entrant). Reusing variables is inherently risking, with the usual advice to minimise scope.

Comment: @davidxxx A new `TestImpl` is created for each call so the lifetime is limited.

Comment: I like this solution, however, as you say, the Impl class might need to access longer lived variables of the Test class. The `run()` method is very large and complex and having it indented will not be easy to read.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin  I understand but from the client side of `TestImpl`, the client may still call `run()` multiple times. A check in `run()` to ensure that the run was not already "consummed" will at least make it to fail at runtime.

Comment: @buydadip if your “`run()` method is very large and complex” then 1) split it into smaller methods and 2) give those methods meaningful names describing their purpose, rather than “run”.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way. Using an exception. So anyone who dares to use `run()` twice gets kicked out.

```
package test;

import com.sun.jdi.IncompatibleThreadStateException;

public class Test{
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    
    public void run() throws IncompatibleThreadStateException{
        if(this.isRunning) {
            throw new IncompatibleThreadStateException();
        }
        else {
            this.isRunning = true;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: PS using `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException` might also be a good exception type for your situation

Comment: I agree: to prevent more than one call, that is the way.  But you should not use `com.sun.jdi.IncompatibleThreadStateException` (sun classes are not standard for developement) but rather a exception such as `IllegalStateException`

Comment: JDI is a debugging interface. You should not make your programs depend on the debugging API, unless you are truly developing a debugging tool.